# (Swift) How to retrieve array -> mapped object data from Firestore Cloud

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from my database but I am having issues with one particular field structure.

The field is an array containing maps, with some map objects being arrays. How can I input my getDocument code to retrieve the data in this field?

Code:

```
// Fetch data from database
func getSlideData() {
    
    // get reference to database
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userInfo.id!)
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let array = document.get("Events") as? [[String: String]]
            
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get the array from Firestore and then access the map objects.

[image: This is how the field is structured.]

This is how the field is structured in Firestore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is almost always impossible to debug code without seeing the code. Obviously.

Comment: "The field is an array containing maps, with some map objects being arrays." The second half of that sentence doesn't make sense to me. An array of dictionaries with some dictionaries being arrays? Also, is every field in the dictionary a string? Why is `dateYear` a string and not a number?

Comment: @bsod Some keys of the dictionary store arrays. I uploaded the picture with my setup to visualize this point - the "images" dictionary key stores an array of image references. For the purposes of my app, the date information is displayed in UILabels, so I stored them as strings to make it easier for myself.